# Style nested divs with no class name specified

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I would like to change styles for nested divs like in example below:

```
<div class="box">  #1
  <div>            #2
    <div>          #3
     <div>         #4
       <div></div> #5
       <div></div> #6
       <div></div> #7 **How to style this div when class name is not present?**
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was able to access div #4 in this way:

```
.box div div div {}
```

But what is the way to access div #5 #6 #7?

Comment: Frankly, you **really** need to start using classes.

Comment: j08691 If you know please show how to acces #7, thanks

Comment: There are ways to do this, but you will be creating a maintenance nightmare. Have a look at the `nth-of-type()` or another of-type selector for one option. (But please do consider whether this is the best approach)

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access #7 you have a two or three options **all** of which use the direct descendant selector `>` to limit the context to children of the #4 div.

```
.box div div div > div:last-of-type{}
/* assumes there are no additional divs after #7 */
```

or

```
.box div div div> div:last-child {} 
/* assumes that the div is, in fact, the last child
```

or even

```
.box div div div> div:nth-child(3) {}
/* assumes that the 3rd child is a div */
```

Answer (score 2):

With plain CSS you can use the pseudo-class [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```css
div.box > div > div > div > div:last-child {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">  
  <div>            
    <div>          
     <div>         
       <div>5</div> 
       <div>6</div> 
       <div>7</div> 
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If those last three `div` elements were really intended to have no content, there's a shortcut:

`.box div:empty:after { content: 'I am empty'; }  /* all of them */`

`.box div:empty:nth-child(1):after { content: 'Child 1'; }  /* specific */`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by following line of css

```css
.box div:nth-child(3) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">  
  <div>   
  1
    <div>  
      2
     <div>    
       3
       <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4</div> 
       <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5</div> 
       <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;7</div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```